# How to customize grid jquery struts2 plugin to add hyperlink

Tags: java, html, struts2

I am going to user grid to show data.
i am looking following examples.
http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-grid-showcase/index.action
as like first example i want to populate simply data no edit no inline edit navigation buttons
I just want to add 2 more columns which contains hyperlink as
") >Edit
") >Update

In documentation also there not clearly mentioned this.

Please tell me what should be done?

Thanks

Comment: if you had a solution plz share it.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a formatter function to the column.

```
 <@sjg.gridColumn 
        name="name" 
        index="name" 
        title="Name" 
        sortable="true" 
        align="center" 
        formatter="nameFormatter"
        search="true"
        searchoptions="{sopt:['cn']}"
        />
```

you then define a small javascript function nameFormatter like this:

```
function nameFormatter(cellvalue,options,row) {
        return '<a href="your_link?id=' + row.someId +">' + cellvalue + '</a>';
    }
```

where cellvalue is the actual name of the original cell, and row.someId is, for example, some id you get from another column. This will result is something like:

```
<a href="your_link?id=34">Foo</a>
```

Hope this helps